# Connecting 8pin/6+8pin RTX 2060 to 2x6+2 pin Chieftec CTG-750C?

Tags: graphics-cards, power-supply

I see that the Nvidia RTX 2060 comes with 8pin or 6+8pin power ports, but my power supply, Chieftec CTG-750C, only has 2x6+2 pin power ports.

- Which RTX 2060 should I buy so I can connect it to my power supply?
- Do I need some sort of adapter and will this work well under-load (games) with my power supply?

Comment: A 6+2 pin PCIe power connector *is* an 8-pin connector. Almost every power supply has these connectors with the 2 extra pins on a separate piece to allow compatibility with both 6-pin and 8-pin sockets on graphics cards. If your PSU has 2x6+2 connectors, then it supports *any* RTX 2060 with 2 or less PCIe power sockets.

Comment: @Romen Should probably post this as an answer ;)